# Mysql update with crossreference not Having item

Tags: mysql

sorry i wrote in german... Here again...

I'm stuck and hope you can help me!

I have a mysql database with two tables: booking and article. They are linked via booking.Uid and article.booking_Uid. There can be several articles in each booking.

I want to change booking.status to "Ready for price" of all bookings if there is an article in this booking that has the value "xxx" in the tid field. So far so simple...
In addition, there may not be an article with price = 9999 in this booking.

This last point is where I fail!

Thank you in advance

```
UPDATE booking
SET status = 'Preis-fertig'
WHERE Uid IN (
    SELECT Uid
    FROM (
        SELECT b.Uid
        FROM booking b
        JOIN article a ON b.Uid = a.booking_Uid
        WHERE a.tid = 'xxx' AND a.price != 9999
    ) AS subquery
);
```

Second Part is wrong....

Comment: Use not a subquery but multiple-table UPDATE syntax.

Comment: But IT is only one table i need to update....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> change booking.status to "Ready for price" of all bookings if there is an article in this booking that has the value "xxx" in the tid field.
>
> In addition, there may not be an article with price = 9999 in this booking.

If these conditions must refer to the same row then:

```
UPDATE booking b
JOIN article a ON b.Uid = a.booking_Uid
SET b.status = 'Preis-fertig'
WHERE a.tid = 'xxx' AND a.price != 9999
```

If these conditions may refer to different rows then:

```
UPDATE booking b
JOIN article a ON b.Uid = a.booking_Uid
LEFT JOIN article a1 ON b.Uid = a1.booking_Uid AND a1.price = 9999
SET b.status = 'Preis-fertig'
WHERE a.tid = 'xxx' 
  AND a1.booking_Uid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE booking
SET status = 'Preis-fertig'
WHERE Uid IN (
    SELECT b.Uid
    FROM booking b
    INNER JOIN article a ON b.Uid = a.booking_Uid
    WHERE a.tid = 'xxx'
    AND b.Uid NOT IN (
        SELECT booking_Uid
        FROM article
        WHERE price = 9999
    )
);
```

Comment: This is not working... due to You can't specify target table 'booking' for update in FROM clause